# Duplicate entry error while generating signed apk

Tags: android

I got this error when building a signed apk in android . Please help me resolve this problem.

The error is:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/compat/R$bool.class

build.gradle for **app** level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.glocar.dealers"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 3
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "1.1.1"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    // retrofit, gson
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'


    //firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
  //  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle for **project** level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }



    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: post your gradle here

Comment: you have a duplicated support library dependencies. Like @quicklearner says, please add your app module build.gradle to your question.

Comment: Here is my build.gradle file for project and app level 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AYwvFYYXDuFXm42KzV0QBa0369Ps7dTy/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove this line:

```
implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
```

And try to use [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) from support library instead of this library

Comment: Updated @user9484702

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably because of the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
```

If you check its [project build.gradle](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/blob/master/build.gradle) and [module build.gradle](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/blob/master/bottom-bar/build.gradle), you will find that it still using support library version `25.3.0` for `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` and `com.android.support:design`

So, you need to exclude both of the support library with:

```
implementation ("com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude module: 'design'
}
```

Please be aware that bottom-bar library is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks the problem has been removed now.
But the problem is not with the library you mentioned but with google libraries. I have use a google service bundled library and also a seprate library for google sign in, which creates a duplication. And I also update each and every library with their updated version no. which removed the problem and signed apk is generated.
Thanks to all Guys.

Comment: That is really a good news! You can create a new answer or you can edit my answer which can be helpful for everyone who stumbled with the same problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Update version [26.0.0] to some new version, all support dependencies must have same version then clean project and run again

Answer (score 1):

I am get rid of this problem by updating each and every library with their updated versions.
And previously I used google bundled library + google seprate library for login which creates a duplication. So i removed bundled library and use seprate library for google sign in and then clean the project 
and thats it.